# I can't get correct emaid, phone number for a name

Tags: android

> {"name":["bineesh","Administrator","binu","binu","bijith","prem","rahul"],"email":["feawfewa@gmail.com","jytfj@gmail.com","werw@gmail.com","543534@gmail.com","nvbnb@gmail.com","gdfgd@gmail.com","utyuty@gmail.com"],"phone":["345366","12345","0","0","0","979797","7655775"]}

JSON parsing using to I retrieve all the name value. I showed that name in a list view but when I click first name I can't get correct email, and phone number for name

Please help.

```
          JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject(result);
          JSONArray ja = myJson.getJSONArray("name");
          JSONArray je = myJson.getJSONArray("email");
          JSONArray jp = myJson.getJSONArray("phone");


          int length=ja.length();
          List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             // employeeText.setText(ja.getString(i));
              System.out.println(ja.getString(i));


              listContents.add(ja.getString(i));
          }



          ArrayAdapter<String> a=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listContents);
          setListAdapter(a);




 }

            catch(JSONException e1){
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No name found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();


            }




      }
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(id==0)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < je.length(); i++) {
             // employeeText.setText(ja.getString(i));
              try {
                System.out.println(je.getString(0));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    Intent i=new Intent(Employeedetail.this,details.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Please show respect for the people trying to help you by bothering to re-read your message before posting it and fixing the worst of the typos. Also, use the **[?]** link above the text input area to find out how to correctly format code and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead i would suggest you create a JSON Array with object.

**One Object is having name, email and phone values.**

Because you just have to get an object from particular position only. It would also decrease load of this comparison.

Comment: for example i clik "bineesh"(name) then show all the email in a list but i want bineesh's correct email id how can?